# How to find a table in a big diagram?

Tags: mysql-workbench

Using MySQL Workbensh 6.3.7 on Windows 10, I am finding the search behavior strange.

There is an entry box that you could use to enter the name of the table, however, this does not work every time! I mean it sometimes finds the table and sometimes it does not! When it works, it is very good. I can enter 1 or more chars from start and the tool would highlight the table in the diagram, for some tables, even entering the full name, it does not find the table!

If I go to a specific table from the tree on the left-hand-side nav, and double click the table, it opens its properties, but it does not select it on the drawing area!

I have generated the DDL and searched it as text to find columns and relations then traced that back manually but this is difficult for large diagrams.

I want to be able to search for a table (even with wild card) and find it in the drawing surface - Also, what does the dot at the right side of the table name in the schema treeview mean?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The search behavior sounds like a bug to me. It should always select the table figures that match. When you file a bug report for that (http://bugs.mysql.com) it can be fixed.

The dot in the catalog treeview is just an indicator which db object has been placed already on the current diagram.

A tip: use layers to organize bigger diagrams. Use colors for different groups of db objects, like this:

[image]

You can change the colors on the Properties tab in the lower left corner, even for multiple figures in one step.

And don't forget you can increase the size of the diagram to fit more figures on it. See the menu `Model -> Diagram Properties and Size...`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not sure if the community edition allow for colors...I will check. It looks like you are using the tool in a system other than Windows...Just guessing.